# How to create a circuit which is sensitive to inputs change and results to output change?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, design

Suppose that we need a circuit with 4 inputs `A0-A3` and 1 output `out`.  when one of the inputs changes (for example `0000` changes to `0001`) the output switches to another state. after that for the next input change (for example `0001` to `0010` or any other random state) the output switches to another state again. suppose that the initial state of the circuit is input: `0000` and output: `0`.

How to design such circuit?

Comment: By starting with an accurate specification of the problem, and following any approach to (useful search term) "state machine design".

Comment: If you want combinational logic, it's just a f(x). Design the logic according to the truth table, and if you wish, you can simplify it manually. If you want sequential logic, it's an FSM. However, the *next state* part is still combinational logic. If the same current `A0-A3` inputs but different input transition (`0001`->`0010`, or `1000`->`0010`) can lead to different `out` output, you need FSM.

Comment: As you know as a regular questioner, the site is not a free design house or on-line tutorial service. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Describe the circuit you are making and what it is for. Show your own work and your own findings in considerable detail with any schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract.

Comment: no it is not a fixed truth table. 0000 can results to output 0 and 1 in different situations. suppose that input is 0000 and output is 0. 0000 changes to 0001 and output changes to 1. next 0001 changes to 0010 and output changes to 0 and again input changes back to 0000 and output changes to 1. there is 0000 with 2 outputs 0 and1 in different situations.

Comment: Old school TTL 1 of 16 decoder

Comment: @sadeghyeganehzadeh   `0001` to `0010` is two changes ...  expect them to not be simultaneous

Comment: @jsotola - excuse me that's right. suppose 0001 to 0011

Comment: what is the solution? please help me.

Comment: `0001 to 0011` ... how many bits are different between the two sets of inputs?

Comment: at first glance, it appears that the output of `1` signifies an odd number of `1` inputs, so @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 comment applies here

Comment: The OP needs to accurately and completely define a rule that gives his desired output for all possible state transitions before he can move on to designing a solution. At the moment he has defined what he wants for 3 transitions and changed his mind about one of them. 65536 * 65535 - 3 state transitions to go. So, preferably a simple rule.

Comment: Look up TTL 1 of 16 decoder and you will the answer in the data sheet how it’s done !!

Answer (score 1):

Each input goes to a edge detector which outputs a pulse. It needs to detect either edge. Like this one: [dual edge detector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55327429/how-to-create-an-asynchronous-edge-detector-in-vhdl)
[image]

Those outputs are then ORed together (4 input OR gate) to a D-Flop clock input.  Connect \$\overline{Q}\$ output to input \$D\$